# get id value when max is on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

is this the best way to get the id value of the most recent date?

```
table1
id,entrydate
1,8/23/2012
2,8/24/2012
3,8/23/2012

select id from table1 where entrydate = ( select MAX(entrydate) from table1 )
```

Comment: What if more than one ID share the same date?

Comment: @Rod sql server, oracle, sybase, mysql, what?

Comment: sorry about that i should have added the time as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL-Server, you can use `ORDER BY` and then take one row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id
FROM table
ORDER BY entrydate DESC
```

In MySql it is `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
ORDER BY entrydate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

In Oracle:

```
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY entrydate DESC) 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: you can also order by id desc to give the biggest id, what do you think?

Comment: @aF.: Why do you think that this is the same? `entrydate` could be independent to the order of creation or the id could be created manually.

Comment: What I mean is: `ORDER BY entrydate DESC, id DESC` and not `ORDER BY id DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a good way there. I'd watch out for ties:

```
select top id from table1 where entrydate = ( select MAX(entrydate) from table1 )
```

This, of course, assuming you are using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY entrydate DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is not present in all database types.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do `SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY entrydate DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, you want to do this:

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, MAX(entrydate) FROM table1 GROUP BY id
```

For MySQL:

```
SELECT id, MAX(entrydate) FROM table1 GROUP BY id LIMIT 1
```